# Slicing happens even after catching by reference

Tags: c++, exception

I think my understanding has an dent here and would like to clarify few things. It is true that we should always follow golden rule, throw by value, catch by reference. AND if I throw derived object, and catch by base, extra parts of derived would be sliced. BUT when I throw an derived object, and catch an base object by reference, slicing should not happen. Right?

Consider this code:

```
class Base {
  public:
    void print() {
      std::cout << "base print" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    void d_print() {
      std::cout << "derived print" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
  try {
    Derived d;
    throw d;
  } catch (Base& db) {
    db.print();
    db.d_print();
  }
}
```

This does not compile. I thought there would not be any slicing and db.d_print() would call the d_print of Derived. What did I miss?

Comment: If you wanted polymorphic behaviour, you need to mark the base classes method as virtual.

Comment: This has nothing to do with throwing exceptions. `Derived d; Base& b = d; b.d_print();` wouldn't work eiter.

Comment: ...catch by **const** reference...

Comment: There is no "d_print" method in the `Base` class. This has nothing to do with exceptions. Exceptions do not change how C++ objects work fundamentally. If some function in your code receives a `Base &` as a parameter, it can't call some method called `d_print` on it, because it does not exist in `Base`.

Comment: @Mansoor, Yes. That is right. It works and I know that. What I do not know is that what is the point of not slicing the things here. It is good to slice here anyway then. Right?

Comment: @tkausl, I concur. I have written more in above comment.

Comment: @HemantBhargava I see no slicing happening.  The issue is that you are trying to call a function that doesn't exist in `B`.  Slicing occurs when you pass by value, not when you pass by reference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, That is correct. I agree. You say slicing is not happening. My point is that if I can not call d_print(), then slice should happen in these cases anyway. Isn;t that correct?

Comment: The issue is a syntax one, not a slicing one.  C++ works this way -- on the left side of the `.` or `->` you need an object that has implemented that function.  `Base` did not implement `d_print` -- it is the `Derived` that has implemented that function.  Since no slicing has occurred, you could cast the `B` to a `D`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thanks for coming by. I understand object slicing. My point here is that, please understand this, since we are not allowed to use d_print() in this case, it would have been nicer to slice this function. Isn't it?

Comment: *It would have been nicer to slice this function. Isn't it?* -- No, it would not have been nicer.  It is perfectly legitimate for a programmer to know, by whatever means, that the type being passed is really a `Derived`, and thus give the programmer the option to cast to that type.

Answer (score 1):

> Slicing happens even after catching by reference

No. Slicing did not happen.

The reference refers to the base sub object of the thrown derived object. It is still a reference to base, and thus you cannot refer to members of a derived class. After all, there are no guarantees that a reference to base refers to base sub object of any particular derived class.

If you want to access the names of the derived type, then you should catch reference to the derived type instead. If you want to have specific behaviour when you catch particular subclass, then you can use virtual function to achieve that.

Comment: I agree slicing did not happen. Which is good. 

My point here is that, please understand this, since we are not allowed to use d_print() in this case, it would have been nicer to slice this function. Isn't it?

Comment: @HemantBhargava Why? What advantage is there to make a copy of the base object?

Comment: If an object is sliced, one of the things that gets sliced off is polymorphic behaviour. Right? And wouldn't that save some time. Not an expert though.

Actually, I would like to answer an back question:
What disadvantage is there to make a copy of base object?

Comment: @HemantBhargava Slicing is copying of the base sub object without copying the rest of the derived object. Disadvantage of copying is that it can potentially be slower than not copying.

Comment: Yeah. That is what I wanted to convey that it would be SLOWER in this case. It would have been faster if copying of base object might have happened. Cheers!